# How to Fix "IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable" in Code

Tags: python, physics, index-error

```
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
M = 1.0 # Mass of discus in kg
g = 9.81 # Acceleration due to gravity (m/s^2)
V = 30 # Initial velocity in m/s
ang = 30 # Angle of initial velocity in degrees
Cd = 0.54 # Drag coefficient
Cl = 0.87
dt = 0.01 # time step in s
t = [0]
vx = [V*np.cos(ang/180*np.pi)]
vy = [V*np.sin(ang/180*np.pi)]
x = [0]
y = [1.8]
rho = 1.2 #density in kg/m^3
a_ref = 0.025 #area in m^2
gamma = 35/180*np.pi


drag=0.5 * rho * V**2 * a_ref * Cd
lift = 0.5 * rho * V**2 * a_ref * Cl
ax = ((rho*V**2*a_ref)/(2*M))*(-Cl *np.sin(gamma) - Cd * np.cos(gamma))
ay = ((rho*V**2*a_ref)/(2*M))*(Cl* np.cos(gamma) - Cd* np.sin(gamma)) -g

counter = 0

while (y[counter] >= 0):
    t.append(t[counter]+dt)
    vx.append(vx[counter]+dt*ax[counter])
    vy.append(vy[counter]+dt*ay[counter])
    x.append(x[counter]+dt*vx[counter])
    y.append(y[counter]+dt*vy[counter])
    vel = np.sqrt(vx[counter+1]**2 + vy[counter+1]**2)
    drag = 0.5 * rho * V**2 * a_ref * Cd
    lift = 0.5 * rho * V**2 * a_ref * Cl
    ax.append(((rho*V**2*a_ref)/(2*M))*(-Cl *np.sin(gamma) - Cd * np.cos(gamma)))
    ay.append(((rho*V**2*a_ref)/(2*M))*(Cl* np.cos(gamma) - Cd* np.sin(gamma)) -g)
    counter = counter +1

plt.plot(x,y,'ro')
plt.title("Womens Discus!")
plt.ylabel("y (m)")
plt.xlabel("x (m)")
```

I need to fix this error, in the line "`vx.append(vx[counter]+dt*ax[counter])`", yet I'm a bit clueless as to how and have been staring at this problem for hours now. I was not allowed to attach my entire code (too long) so I just removed variables and some equations.

Please let me know if I need to add anything in order to help solve this issue
Any help would be greatly appreciated. TIA

Comment: When you shortened the code, you unfortunately left out parts that are important to solve the problem. If you'd like help on how to come up with a more helpful piece of code, please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: just updated the code with missing variables/equations.  :)

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by the fact that you're trying to index the variable `ax`. This variable is a numpy scalar, so it can't be indexed.

Answer (score 0):

try changing the version of your numpy package
(downgrading the package helped me)